# Laravel query builder returning more rows than it should

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

Have table structure like:

```
 properties
 ------------
 id
 property_name

 buildings
 -------------
 id
 building_name
 property_id

 floors
 -------------
 id
 floor_coode
 building_id

 units
 -------------
 id
 unit_number
 floor_id

 amenities
 ------------
 id
 amenity_name
 amenity_value
 unit_id

 categories
 -----------
 id
 category_name
 parent_id

amenity_categories
 ------------
amenity_id
category_id
```

Now, I tried to run following query:

```
        $query = \DB::table('amenities')
            ->join('units', 'units.id', 'amenities.unit_id')
            ->join('floors', 'floors.id', 'units.floor_id')
            ->join('buildings', 'buildings.id', 'floors.building_id')
            ->join('properties', 'properties.id', 'buildings.property_id')
            ->leftjoin('amenity_category', 'amenities.id', 'amenity_category.amenity_id')
            ->leftjoin('categories', 'categories.id', 'amenity_category.category_id')
            ->select('amenities.id as ame_id', 'amenities.amenity_name', 'amenities.amenity_value','units.id as unit_id', 'units.unit_number','amenity_category.*','categories.parent_id as cat_parent_id')
            ->where('buildings.id',$building_id)
            ->orderBy('units.unit_number','asc');

        $data = $query->get();
```

With this, it is returning more row than it should be for example lets look a chunk of particular unit:107

```
[300] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ame_id] => 2
                    [amenity_name] => CU
                    [amenity_value] => 20
                    [unit_id] => 1
                    [unit_number] => 107
                    [amenity_id] => 2
                    [category_id] => 8
                    [cat_parent_id] => 5
                )

            [301] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ame_id] => 3
                    [amenity_name] => VR
                    [amenity_value] => 50
                    [unit_id] => 1
                    [unit_number] => 107
                    [amenity_id] => 
                    [category_id] => 
                    [cat_parent_id] => 
                )

            [302] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ame_id] => 4
                    [amenity_name] => SF
                    [amenity_value] => 320
                    [unit_id] => 1
                    [unit_number] => 107
                    [amenity_id] => 4
                    [category_id] => 6
                    [cat_parent_id] => 5
                )

            [303] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ame_id] => 1
                    [amenity_name] => BO
                    [amenity_value] => 20
                    [unit_id] => 1
                    [unit_number] => 107
                    [amenity_id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 6
                    [cat_parent_id] => 5
                )

            [304] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ame_id] => 4
                    [amenity_name] => SF
                    [amenity_value] => 320
                    [unit_id] => 1
                    [unit_number] => 107
                    [amenity_id] => 4
                    [category_id] => 9
                    [cat_parent_id] => 5
                )

            [305] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ame_id] => 1
                    [amenity_name] => BO
                    [amenity_value] => 20
                    [unit_id] => 1
                    [unit_number] => 107
                    [amenity_id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 8
                    [cat_parent_id] => 5
                )

            [306] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ame_id] => 4
                    [amenity_name] => SF
                    [amenity_value] => 320
                    [unit_id] => 1
                    [unit_number] => 107
                    [amenity_id] => 4
                    [category_id] => 10
                    [cat_parent_id] => 5
                )

            [307] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ame_id] => 1
                    [amenity_name] => BO
                    [amenity_value] => 20
                    [unit_id] => 1
                    [unit_number] => 107
                    [amenity_id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 9
                    [cat_parent_id] => 5
                )

            [308] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ame_id] => 4
                    [amenity_name] => SF
                    [amenity_value] => 320
                    [unit_id] => 1
                    [unit_number] => 107
                    [amenity_id] => 4
                    [category_id] => 11
                    [cat_parent_id] => 5
                )

            [309] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ame_id] => 1
                    [amenity_name] => BO
                    [amenity_value] => 20
                    [unit_id] => 1
                    [unit_number] => 107
                    [amenity_id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 10
                    [cat_parent_id] => 5
                )

            [310] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ame_id] => 2
                    [amenity_name] => CU
                    [amenity_value] => 20
                    [unit_id] => 1
                    [unit_number] => 107
                    [amenity_id] => 2
                    [category_id] => 6
                    [cat_parent_id] => 5
                )
```

Here, you can see actually there are only 4 different `ame_id` ranging from 1-4 and that how it should be returned. Where I am doing wrong? Also, removing that pivot table is not the idea as I also need to load that relation data as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use groupby to get unique rows

```php
$query = \DB::table('amenities')
    ->join('units', 'units.id', 'amenities.unit_id')
    ->join('floors', 'floors.id', 'units.floor_id')
    ->join('buildings', 'buildings.id', 'floors.building_id')
    ->join('properties', 'properties.id', 'buildings.property_id')
    ->leftjoin('amenity_category', 'amenities.id', 'amenity_category.amenity_id')
    ->leftjoin('categories', 'categories.id', 'amenity_category.category_id')
    ->select('amenities.id as ame_id', 'amenities.amenity_name', 'amenities.amenity_value','units.id as unit_id', 'units.unit_number','amenity_category.*','categories.parent_id as cat_parent_id')
    ->where('buildings.id',$building_id)
    ->orderBy('units.unit_number','asc')
    ->groupby('amenities.id');

$data = $query->get();
```

Comment: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #7 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'amenity_db.amenity_category.category_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: will be simply solved by changing the sql mode in MySQL by this command,
    SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));    

when using set statement, this change is for runtime only. when your server restarts, you change will be overridden. you can make changes in my.ini and restart your server for permanent changes in mysql configuration

Comment: I don't think thats the best practice so far.

Answer (score 0):

That's the right behavior of the database & eloquent. Otherwise you have to leave out the columns, which cause the duplicates like category_id. Or you have to work with subqueries, where you pre-select the only categories you want.

OR

Can't you work with eloquent relations and eager loading?
Then get all amenities like:

```
$amenities = Amenity::all()->with('units.floors');
```

and when using them

```
foreach($amenities as $amenity){
    units = $amenity->unit();
}
```

*code not tested*

UPDATE
You can create a subquery with the query builder like this (example not with generalized tables)

```
$subQuery = DB::table('firsttable')->where('id', 77);
```

And then use it in an other query like this:

```
return DB::table(DB::raw("({$subQuery->toSql()}) as sub"))
           ->leftJoin('secondtable','id', '=', 'secondtable_id')
           ->mergeBindings($subQuery)
           ->get();
```

Hope that helps to point you on the right direction?

Comment: I understand that, however, i have experienced a lot that eloquent is quite slow for bigger tasks. Could you suggest similar approach with query builder like at first query without that pivot table and later call that with amenity value in an efficient way.

Comment: could you suggest the subquery technique?